# passing a negative sign on zero integer to a function kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, math

```
val userInput:Int = -0
fun costumPrint(x:Int){ println(x) } // = 0 <- not i want , -0 <-is what i want
```

how can i print/get exatly what in userInput  (with negative sign) but keep using integer as parameter

Comment: Could you please share the use case for wanting `-0` instead of `0` here?

Comment: Two's complement (which is what most computers use for representing signed integers) doesn't have the concept of negative zero. The Kotlin compiler might accept the expression `-0` but still treat it exactly the same as `0`.

Comment: If you really want to represent user input, the user input is textual, so a `String` would be more appropriate and would keep the `-` sign. If what you want is the *value* entered by the user, then `-0` and `0` is the same value, and it shouldn't matter much. That's why I'm asking why you need the distinction here.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin (JVM, and generally most) Integers, do not have positive and negative zero.
Some other people have noted Strings, but maybe a Float or Double would suit your use case, as those have 2 values of 0. Note that that would be very hacky and I discourage you, so probably just go for strings